# Oracle enhanced with rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We have migrated our app from Rails 2.2 to rails 3.1  and started using activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1

I keep seeing this sql in my logs when the app loads and when any request comes to the server.

```
  (102.0ms)  SELECT DECODE(table_name, UPPER(table_name), LOWER(table_name), table_name) FROM all_tables WHERE owner = SYS_CONTEXT('userenv', 'session_user') AND secondary = 'N'
   (102.4ms)  SELECT DECODE(table_name, UPPER(table_name), LOWER(table_name), table_name) FROM all_tables WHERE owner = SYS_CONTEXT('userenv', 'session_user') AND secondary = 'N'
   (101.2ms)  SELECT DECODE(table_name, UPPER(table_name), LOWER(table_name), table_name) 
.....
```

Almost 21 queries at one time ..

When i digged into the library the origin of the statement is

```
 class OracleEnhancedAdapter 
    def tables
```

Can anyone tell me why these sqls are fired everytime. This behavior was not seen in rails 2.2 .

Does it affect the performance of the app  or is it routine ?

Answer (score 2):

This happens during the first request to the application. It's pretty routine for ActiveRecord to get the list of table names from the database for the connected user.

This query will be fired only once (not per request but every time the server is started). This is specific to the database adapter implementation.

For e.g, the `sqlite3-ruby` gem fires an equivalent query:

> SQL (0.6ms)   SELECT name  FROM sqlite_master  WHERE type = 'table'
>   AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'